# Matrix transpose algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, matrix

If I have a `List<List<T>` like the following :

```
Name    City   Id
Anna     NY     1
Joe      NJ     2
```

How can I transpose it efficiently in order to have :

```
Name    Anna     Joe
City    NY       NJ
Id      1        2
```

I tried the following

```
public static void MatrixTranspose<T>(ref List<List<T>> matrix)
{                
   var h = matrix.Count - 2;
   var w = matrix[0].Count - 1;

   for (var i = 0; i < h; ++i)
   {
      for (var j = i + 1; j < w; ++j)
      {
          var tmp = matrix[i][j];
          matrix[i][j] = matrix[j][i];
          matrix[j][i] = tmp;
       }
   }
}
```

That seems to be working on paper I believe? But I feel like I'm doing too much permutations. Is there a way to optimize it? Also, is the use of ref correct here?

Comment: _That seems to be working on paper i believe?_ so you didn't actually test the code?

Comment: Few notes: is your _matrix_ always square? If not then you have a bug. Is it List<List<T>> the proper type to use? Do you have the option to change it? ref has no use here because you never reassign its value to a new list. Performance? Worst case, probably, but it's probably also the easier to read. Do you have a **measured** performance issue?

Comment: @t3chb0t : I tried, didn't work apparently. As Adriano Repetti pointed out, i'm out of range if i don't have a squared matrix.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Matrix not always square, i saw the bug. List of List isn't necessarily the proper type to use, i can change it. In my context i just needed a place to store a collection of lists generated by the same loop. I transpose it because i need to foreach on the lines and serialize each line separatly later, so i want the lines to becomes the column for easier manipulations. Due to the version of .NET i'm using, i can't use Tuple and I can't use a Dictionnary because my keys would actually be a string, which is impossible.

Comment: Well, you might consider `string[,]` or even `string[][]`. Or you may let it be `List<List<string>>` but avoid to _transpose the matrix_. If it's only for visualization/serialization purposes then you just need to read values in the other order. Even better...create a `View` of underlying type and keep consumers unaware of its implementation/storage. Just few ideas to consider.

Comment: My item in the list is reference type, so i can't do string tabs. I think i'll just loop in the "inner" list<T> and then in the "outer" list<T> to extract the lines and put it in a brand new temporary List just to pass it to appropriate methods. However now that i wondered how to transport a non squared matrix, i'm still interested in the algorithm

Comment: I can't understand why you think it's impossible for a dictionary to use string as the key.  Is there a reason you can't use a class(`List<Person>`)?  This way you can organize how the data is displayed without changing anything.

Answer (score 3):

> is the use of ref correct here?

Taken from MSDN: [ref (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx)

> The ref keyword causes an argument to be passed by reference, not by value. The effect of passing by reference is that any change to the parameter in the called method is reflected in the calling method. For example, if the caller passes a local variable expression or an array element access expression, and the called method replaces the object to which the ref parameter refers, then the caller’s local variable or the array element now refer to the new object.

The point of `ref` is to pass a value type (struct) to a method as if it was reference type (class). `List<T>` is a class, so there's no need to add `ref`in this scenario as it's just acting as another level of redirection. Think of it as being a pointer to a pointer.

The problem with using `List<List<T>` is that the size of the nested lists could differ from the top-level list and this wouldn't be a matrix. I'd recommend that you use something with a guaranteed rectangular structure, such as `T[,]`. i.e:

```
public static void MatrixTranspose<T>(ref T[,] matrix)
{
    int columns = matrix.GetLength(0);
    int rows = matrix.GetLength(1);
    T[,] transposed = new T[rows, columns];
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < columns; column++)
        {
            transposed[row, column] = matrix[column, row];
        }
    }

    // Reassign matrix so that it gets picked up by ref.
    matrix = transposed;
}
```